# How to calc inner product of two vectors by stl container and algorithm libraries?

Tags: c++, c++11, std

sure there are many ways:

```
assert(v1.size() == v2.size());
for (auto&& i = 0; i < v1.size(); ++i) {
    acc += v1[i]*v2[i];
}
```

but there is a `zip` operator in python, so python code would be easy as following codes:

```
acc = accumulate([ele1 * ele2 for ele1, ele2 in zip(v1, v2)])
```

my question is: are there any similar approaches to write some codes as styled as python code? especially by std::algorithm library.

Comment: [std::inner_product](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inner_product)?

Comment: A note on your python: you probably shouldn't eagerly construct a list to pass to accumulate, and instead give it an equivalent generator `accumulate(ele1 * ele2 for ele1, ele2 in zip(v1, v2))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on @G.M.'s comment

Given

```
std::vector<int> v1, v2;
assert(v1.size() == v2.size());
```

You can get an inner product

```
auto acc = std::inner_product(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), 0);
```

Note that the second range is only passed as a start. `std::inner_product`'s precondition equivalent to `v1.size() <= v2.size()`, which is weaker than what you specify.

Comment: As usual with `std::accumulate`, care should be done for last parameter to have correct type (`0` != `0.f`, `int` vs `float`).

Comment: Hence the preceding "Given `std::vector<int>` ..."

Comment: Whereas you notice it, future readers might be surprised. just wanted to highlight the possible mistake.